# Qt VS 2012 Add-in

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012

I have a c++ code that gets all necessary user inputs from .csv file. Now, I’m trying to modify it, so that UI does all the jobs, and have chosen Qt for this task. Completed all my Qt add-in configurations and stuffs for Visual Studio 2012, and here I stuck with my classes. When I make changes in .ui file it doesn’t make any changes to existing header and source files. Instead, all changes are applied to the new files which is located under “Generated Files”.

Can someone explain nice and clear, what exactly is happening here, and how I’m gonna link my existing code to the .ui file?

Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand 100% but everything sounds correct to me. You update the `ui`-file -> the `c++` and `h` files in `GeneratedFiles` are updated. You leave them as they are and include them in your own classes.

Comment: Qt generates ui_*.h files, based on your *.ui files (which are xml). You may look inside of them - they are very simple. Modifying of your *.ui files does not affect your own code.

Comment: It is not clear for me, what you mean by "link my existing code to the .ui file"? Code is .cpp + *.h files. Ui is XML files. Qt generates CPP code, based on .ui files and you may use it in your code.